# Can't get laravel's polymorphic relationship to work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to get a polymorphic relationship working on laravel but every test I make returns either null or ax exception on laravel's pretended SQL query...

FYI: My laravel version is `5.8` running on a `MySQLserver 5.7` (WAMP package)

According to what I read on laravel's docs, I think I must use `morphTo()` in the polymorphic model's class and `morphMany()` on it's children tables, so I coded like this:

**App\Models\Company**

```php
public function accounts(){
    return $this->morphMany(Accountable::class, 'accountable');
}
```

**App\Models\Account\Accountable**

```php
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

public function accountable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Migrations:

**companies**

```php
Schema::create($this->tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    ...
})
```

**bank_accounts migration**

```php
Schema::create('bank_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    ...
});
```

**company_has_accounts migration**

```php
Schema::create('company_has_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->morphs('accountable');
    ...
});
```

### Errors:

The thing is: Whenever I try to debug `BankAccount::find(1)->company` I keep getting:

```sql
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company_has_accounts.company_type' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `company_has_accounts` where `company_has_accounts`.`c
ompany_id` = 1 and `company_has_accounts`.`company_id` is not null and `company_has_accounts`.`company_type` = Financeiro/Models/Account/BankAccount and `company_has_accounts`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

and when I try: `Company::find(1)->accounts` I keep getting an empty Collection.

### My objectives are:

**App\Models\Account\BankAccount**

```php
public function company()
```

To return a App\Models\Company Object.

**App\Models\Account\Company**

```php
public function accounts()
```

To return a collection of mixed "App\Models\Account\BankAccount" and "App\Models\Account\CreditCard" Objects, all belonging to the current App\Models\Account\Company Model, as filtered by the "company_id" column on "company_has_accounts" table.

Comment: IMHO this question is well written and could have a Reproducible Example, but, it lacks the [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) part. If you want to learn Polymorphic relationships my advice is to start slim with a fresh project with 2 or 3 models and tables following the examples provided in the docs. Then if you find some problems you can ask here with the **minimal** code needed. Not everybody here have the time to read all your code and post a "good" answer, considering that it can have more than one issue and no one wants to post a bad answer.

Comment: I see your point, but let's just say that my work environment doesnt allow me to 'waste time' with this sort of things. So with that in mind I decided to write a question as quickly as possible. That's why my code was so badly indented, by the way...

Comment: oh, and I appreciate all the help with editing the question! just an update: after some more struggling I managed to get _App\Models\Account\BankAccount::company()_ up and running by calling with('company'). Don't have the code here on my home PC, but I'm getting pretty close. Will update the question with the new codes ASAP

Comment: I wish you to get a good answer, my point was to post minimal code, so would be easier to give you a correct answer. Your question is written right but with too much code to read for anyone with spare time, I gave the question more tags to give you more views for a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle I managed to get it working. But since I'm new to Laravel I don't know if it's the best approach...

**App\Models\Account\Accountable**

```php
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

public function accountable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**App\Models\Account\Company**

```php
public function accountables(){
    return $this->hasMany(Accountable::class)->with('accountable');
}

public function accounts(){
    $accountables = $this->accountables();
    $accounts = [];
    if ($accountables->count()) {
        foreach ($accountables->get() as $accountable) {
            $accounts[] = $accountable->accountable;
        }
    }
    $accounts = collect($accounts);

    return $accounts;
}
```

**App\Models\Account\BankAccount**

```php
public function accountable(){
    return $this->morphOne(Accountable::class, 'accountable');
}

public function company(){
    $accountable = ($this->accountable())->with('company');

    return $accountable->first()->company;
}
```